# Convert Java code to C#

Tags: c#, java

Please help convert the following Java code to C# ?

```
String[] titles = new String[] { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta" };
List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
 x.add(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,13,14,15 });
 }
```

And what is this code doing?

Thanks

Comment: This code just repeats `1...15` 4 times. In Python it would just be `4 * [range(1, 15 + 1)]`

Comment: Why are you trying to convert code that you don't understand?

Comment: @BoltClock: there's been a great deal of code I tried to convert that I didn't understand. In fact, trying to convert it was exactly for the purpose of understanding. Why is this not a good way to learn?

Comment: BoltClock, Like Dinah says, it may be helpful.  I'm more comfortable with C# and it's debugging tools.   I find it helpful to view the code execution and examine variables and flow with debuggers, watch, breakpoints etc. There are a lot of different ways to learn and experience things, methinks.

Comment: @Dinah - the way you learn is by working things out for yourself, not by asking someone else to do the work for you.

Comment: @Trey Balut - in that case, it is time got more comfortable with Java and its debuggers.  How are you going to learn that without using them yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code loops through 4 entries of the titles String array and adds a double array with 15 entries to a list called x for each entry in the titles array

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 entries in `titles` so `x` ends up with 4 entries with 1..15 each.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var x = new[] {"Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta"}.Select(title => Enumerable.Range(1, 15).Select(i => (double)i).ToArray()).ToList();
```

Comment: I was just about to post this when it said new answers had been added.

Comment: I honestly didn't expect to get in first :]

Answer (score 0):

The code is almost identical to its C# equivalent.

```
    string[] titles = new string[] { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta" };
    List<double[]> x = new List<double[]>();
    for(int i=0;i<titles.Length;i++) {
         x.Add(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 });
    }
```

This code should work, but I haven't tested it. Let me know if it doesn't work for some reason.

As for what the code is doing, it's just creating a array of strings named titles and filling it with "Alpha" "Beta" "Gamma" and "Delta".

Then it's just creating a list of arrays that store a single double value.

Then it just iterates through the titles array and adds a new array of doubles filled with the numbers 1 through 15 to the x list created earlier.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you Andrew, very helpful, the only change "x.add" to "x.Add"

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll edit the post to avoid any confusion.